# Python installer: "A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run"

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, python

I am on Windows 7 x64, trying to install Python 2.7.5 or 3.3.2. But I'm continuously getting an error showing:

> There is a problem with this Windows installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your package vendor.

I have freshly downloaded the installer package from Python.org several times but it is giving the same error repeatedly.

Here is a picture of the error message as it appears while installing:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might work:

- Go to `C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp` or simply `%LocalAppData%/Temp`.
- Go to `Properties` → `Security`
- Change permission level for everyone to FULL ACCESS.

Comment: ya! it worked for me. But can you explain why does that happened. I am logged in as the administrator but still why ?

Comment: Maybe the installer doesn't have the right privileges? Mind you, the privilege system in Windows is really weird.

Comment: This didn't work for me though the symptoms were similar. Turned out to be a conflicting PIP install. This fixed me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23350061/797945

Comment: Note that "%temp%" is a shortcut to that location.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I think this https://bugs.python.org/issue27564 is the problem, but they claimed to have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

- Run `cmd.exe` (run as administrator)
- Go to Python's location (example: `D:\python\`) by changing the directory
- Write `msiexec /i filename.msi`, e.g. `msiexec /i python-3.4.1.amd64.msi`
- Then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I had extraneous Python environment variables from previous installations. You should delete any Python environment variables and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to install 32 bit version on x64. Tried again with correct version and problem solved.

The automatic download I was given for Windows was the 32-bit version, not the 64-bit version. I scrolled down through all the releases, found 2.7.13 (most recent version as of 10/Aug/17), and specifically downloaded the 64-bit version;
[image: Python releases for Windows]

Once I had downloaded the 64-bit version I installed with no issues.[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details. One line answer do not count as good one.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an older version (Python 3.4.3) and it worked fine.

See the old releases here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

(Fully updated Windows 8.1 64-bit PC, and I tried several of the newer versions, none worked. I also ran a Virus scan, and disabled Antivirus, same error.)

Answer (score 0):

%temp% on run window then Go  after That Temp folder - Go to organize- propertiese - share - everyone .Then again Run installation it will work100%